# Can we use "How dare you + verb" for past action?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

In the dictionary, we have

> [how dare you](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dare_1#dare_idmg_2), etc.
>
> ​used to show that you are angry about something that somebody has
> done
>
> *How dare you talk to me like that?*
>
> *How dare she imply that I was lying?*

It seems that "**How dare you + verb**" is used for present actions

Can we use it for past action?

For example, can we say "*How dare you did that to me yesterday?*"?

But that seems  wrong because the verb "**did**".

We can say "**How did you dare to do that to me?**" but I am not sure if it is idiomatic to say so.

**Do we have a better way to say it?**

Answer (score 3):

No, we can't say *how dare you did that?* because *dare* is the present tense.

*How did/could you dare to do that?* is possible, but *How dared you?* is more idiomatic. See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158840/how-dared-you-versus-how-dare-you).

There is also an archaic past tense, *durst*, but not many people would recognise that today.

Comment: I durst not comment, save to say that I think we can use a present tense verb after 'how dare...' even if the act is well in the past. My father sold my guitar in 1972. How dare he do that! How dare you eat my supper last night!